# how should I import js code from the appDataDir?

Tags: tauri

I'm trying to build a Tauri app using React. I want to be able to load plugins for the app from the AppData folder. I tried to use dynamic import but I got the error:`Not allowed to load local resource:`

I already checked that `tauri.conf.json > tauri > security > csp` is `null` and changed the `tauri > allowlist > fs > scope` to `["**"]`.

the only workaround I found was to use `eval(await fs.readTextFile(await path.appDataDir()))` or Function constructor, but it doesn't look like the most secure solution.

(working with windows 11)